# Empty Partitions created during spark dataset write to HDFS

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs

Trying to save the dataset/dataframe as parquets to hdfs using write method.
Partions are craeted in HDFS but with empty data. I am using Spark version - 2.x

```
dataset.write.mode("append").partitionBy("empNo").format("parquet").save("hdfs path")
```

or

```
dataset.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).save("hdfs path")
```

Please suggest

Comment: Have you set the `dynamic.partition` to `true` and `dynamic.partition.mode` to `nonstrict` for your `HiveContext`?

Comment: No.But Is it required in this write operation from spark to hdfs ?

Comment: Sorry, I read your question wrong. I thought you were writing the partitioned data to a hive table.

Comment: so any suggestion ? I have set .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "/user/hive/warehouse") using SparkSession in my application

Comment: Are you sure data is partitioned properly? Maybe there is a skew causing empty partitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just checked it for a dataframe. Partitioned it on a single column as per your query. Two partitioned folders were created inside the output folder with appropriate values. Each folder had a file with extension `.gz.parquet`

I used the following command:

```
df.write.mode(SaveMode.Append)
  .partitionBy("column_name")
  .format("parquet")
  .save("hdfs://namenode/output")
```

I am working with Spark 1.6 so can't check with `DataSet` API.

I think there might be some problems in the partitioning of your data. Some partitions might be empty. The command you wrote is fine.